# i would like to make a multipart form by using multiple divs showing and hiding them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

Here is the jquery portion , will supply jfiddle

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("a.atest").click(function(){

$(this).leanModal();

    $("button, input[type='button']").click(function(){

        $('#contact').hide();

        $('#nextForm').show();

    });

});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/hfes4ugn/

Comment: html code and snippet or jsfiddle will be better

Comment: `$('#nextForm').css("display","block");` and `$('#nextForm').show();` do the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `.show()` and `.hide()`, that way, you won't need to set `display: none` and `display: block` yourself.

It should work like you want, by doing it like this:

```
$("#form1").hide();
$("#form2").show();
```

Just make sure you're using the right selectors. I don't know if it's a typo, but in your code you refer to `#contact` and `#nextForm`, while your divs are called `#form1` and `#form2`.

Also, your click handler is a little weird? You're binding a click handler to all `a` tags (which is never closed), and inside you're binding another click handler to input buttons?

Take a look at my example in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/w2qL0pn6/1/

Comment: thanks for your response. My problem was i had a div wrapped incorrectly.